# AFNetworking PLIST

Tags: plist, afnetworking

I am trying to use AFNetworking with AFPropertyListRequestOperation to download a plist and use it.
Somehow this is not working because it seems AFNetworking does not like the format of the plist or anything else. The block isn't even fired. Instead the error block is fired.

Any hint why this could be?

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9358444/iOS/zet.plist"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFPropertyListRequestOperation *operation = [AFPropertyListRequestOperation propertyListRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id propertyList) {
    //do something
    NSDictionary *myDic = (NSDictionary *)propertyList;
           NSLog(@"%@", myDic);
    NSLog(@"Fired PLIST");
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id propertyList) {
    //error
     NSLog(@"Error PLIST");
}];

[operation start];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log the error for a start - that will give you an indication of what was wrong. Post back if your still stumped.

```
NSLog(@"%@", error);
```

Comment: NSLocalizedDescription=Expected content type {(
    "application/x-plist"
)}, got text/plain, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0xcf84d70>}

Comment: Your server is sending a `content-type` header of `text/plain` for this file.  Either you are pointing at the wrong file, or you need to have your server send the header `application/x-plist`.

Comment: Why does it say it got text/plain? Isn't it a plist? How can I manipulate this?

Comment: That's what your server is sending.  You need to change it on your server.

Comment: Well at the moment it is hosted on Dropbox. I don't think I can do something about this. If I would have another webspace, what kind I need to have to send or to configure that the file is recognized as plist?

Comment: If changing the content type server-side is not an option. Consider downloading the file using a generic method and deserialising the raw data using NSPropertyListSerialization.

Comment: Well....I need to check on my server...at the moment it is coded in UTF-8. What would be the correct one?

Comment: Meanwhile I am using this:     [AFPropertyListRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/plain"]];

Comment: UTF-8 is the encoding type. That should be correct. You need to ensure the content type is application/x-plist. I don't know anything about your server setup but you need to make sure the responsible service method returns application/x-plist as the content type in the response header.

Comment: I think I can do this with .htaccess and define the typ of files.

Comment: Yes. `AddType application/x-plist .plist`